# Low Search: not showing results from custom status

Tags: low-search

Search results are not showing from entries with a custom status. This is the code I'm using:

```
{exp:low_search:results query="{segment_2}" status="open|Home" disable="member_data|category_fields" channel="news-post" orderby_sort="entry_date|desc"}
```

If I change the status of the entry from 'Home' to 'open' it appears in results.

Comment: If you switch out the `low_search:results` tag for the `channel:entries` tag, does that give you the expected entries?

Comment: Yes, the results show using the channel:entries tag. I've updated the code snippet to show you all the parameters I'm using. The version I'm using is 3.3.2

Comment: Please update to the latest version first. If the problem persists, open [a GetSat thread](http://getsatisfaction.com/low) with EE and PHP versions and Template Debugger output.

Comment: I updated the addon but this did not fix the problem. So for now I have used an alternative method to status to filter entries. This seemed a quicker solution to the problem.